How can I query all released versions?
I want to create a release overview on a Confluence page using the JIRA Issue/Filter macro. For this, I need a JQL statement that generates a list of versions.
How can I request a list of released version using JQL?
Sure, I can search for JIRA issues which have been release with a specific version e.g. fixVersion in releasedVersions(projectname), but how can I get a list of these versions itself using JQL?
All my research, including in the Atlassian forums, has only shown ways of how I can search for issues associated with versions.

The JQL language lets you fetch issues according to the filter you have applied or wrote.
there are plugins (free and payed) for what you described, or you can also use REST API with any scripting language you'd like to achieve that.
